# Ajax .load parsing php variable

Tags: php, ajax

How do I parse a php variable through .load in ajax?

Assuming I want to parse $x through .load so it can be used by the php file being loaded ?

```
<script>
$( "#searchTitle" ).load( "<?php echo $baseUrl ?>/hotels/hotelSearchTitle.php", "$x");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want get the variable $x from a PHP page? If yes the best way is:

on PHP:

```
<?php
$x = "Hello World!";
print '{"phpvarx" : "'.$x.'"}';
?>
```

on jQuery Sender page:

```
<script>
$( "#searchTitle" ).load( "<?php echo $baseUrl ?>/hotels/hotelSearchTitle.php",     function(data){
            var myData = $.parseJSON(data);
            var varx = myData.phpvarx;
            alert(varx);
});
</script>
```

If you are trying to send the variable $X to a php page use it:

on PHP page:

```
<?php
$x = $_GET["x"];
echo $x;
?>
```

on jQuery Sender page:

```
<script>
$( "#searchTitle" ).load( "<?php echo $baseUrl ?>/hotels/hotelSearchTitle.php?x=<?php echo $x; ?>");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must have the values of `$baseUrl` and `$x`. PHP executes on server side and then shows the page.

Probably should work like this:

```
<script>
    $( "#searchTitle" ).load( "<?php echo $baseUrl ?>/hotels/hotelSearchTitle.php", "<?php echo $x; ?>");
</script>
```